# how to save custom html form in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to save custom html form with validation rules in database.

Suppose I have a form which has custom fields and different elements like: select, checkbox, radio, text box. All these elements will be saved as a form into the database, so further I'll be able to easily integrate this form anywhere on my site.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can save the html code in col, and in another col you can save json data for the validation options.
For example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="pass" />
```

And for validation:

```
$validation = array(
  'username' => array(
    'regex' => '/\w{6,12}/',
    'error' => 'Username must be 6 - 12 chars'
  ),
  'pass' => array(
    'func'  => 'validate_password',
    'error' => 'Week password'
  )
);

$validation_json_for_db = json_encode( $validation );
```

Example usage:

```
// may be need to receive from db and json_decode parse
$validation = array(
  'username' => array(
    'regex' => '/\w{6,12}/',
    'error' => 'Username must be 6 - 12 chars'
  ),
  'pass' => array(
    'func'  => 'validate_password',
    'error' => 'Week password'
  )
);

$valid_errors = array();
foreach( $validation as $key => $val ){
  if( isset( $_POST[$key] ) ){
    $isValid = false;
    if( isset( $val['func'] ) ){
      $isValid = call_user_func( $val['func'], $_POST[$key] );
    } elseif( isset( $val['regex'] ){
      $isValid = preg_match( $val['regex'], $_POST[$key] );
    }

    if( ! $isValid ){
      $valid_errors[$key] = $val['error'];
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: How to save html form in database